# Marshall DynamoDBMapper object into Map of Attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDBMapper provides way to build the object from Map

[JavaDoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#marshallIntoObject-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-):  public  T marshallIntoObject(Class clazz,
                                Map itemAttributes,
                                DynamoDBMapperConfig config)

**Is there a function which does the opposite of above function? Something which takes DynamoDBMapper object as an input and  vends out Map itemAttributes?**

DynamoDBMapper.save() must be doing the same thing, but I don't want to duplicate the code.

Regards,

Swapnil

Comment: Currently trying out :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/ItemConverter.html#convert-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Will try out: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java#L239

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments, you can use `DynamoDBMapperTableModel`'s [convert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperTableModel.html#convert-T-) method to get a `Map<String, AttributeValue>`.  To get a `DynamoDBMapperTableModel`, you can use DynamoDBMapper's [getTableModel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#getTableModel-java.lang.Class-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-) method.  Then, you can use the `Map<String, AttributeValue>` in a transactional [Put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/Put.html#withItem-java.util.Map-) or [PutRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/PutRequest.html#withItem-java.util.Map-).